# Bind autocomplete textbox based on other event

Tags: asp.net, wpf, mvvm, autocomplete

I am working on one project and i got stuck in a situation where i have two custom autocomplete textbox. I want second autocomplete textbox to be filled based on the 1st autocomplete textbox. [image]

As shown in figure there are two autocomplete textbox. 1st one is for train line and the other is for Station. I want stations to be filled based on Train line. 
In autocomplete textbox if i write anything it calls one class from where i am getting output but not based on train line. I don't know how to get stations based on train line.

Is that possible?

**EDIT**

I am sharing class for station autocomplete Textbox

```
  class StationDataProvider : dragonz.actb.provider.IAutoCompleteDataProvider
    {
        public IEnumerable<string> GetItems(string textPattern)
        {
            List<String> results = new List<string>();
            try
            {
                String _query = "select stationName from station where stationName like '%" + textPattern.Replace("'", "''") + "%'";
                DataTable dt = dataaccess.getdata(_query, "data").Tables[0];
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        results.Add((String)dr[0]);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    results.Add("No Station Found");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }


            return results;
        }
    }
```

Comment: how about using textchanged event of first textbox to fill second textbox

Comment: Both are autocomplete text boxes and both are getting data from separate classes. But let me try your case @shreesha

Comment: @shreesha nop dont get how to get it.

Comment: check this [WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535).I never tried this,hope it will help

Comment: I have the same but thanx anyway

Comment: Can you post some code of the class which the text box calls into? Is the `DataContext` of the above screen same?

Comment: Do you use mvvm pattern?

Comment: How are you doing the autocomplete at the moment? And I presume that your `stations` table has a column for the `trainline`?

Comment: @petethepagan-gerbil I have one other table which is having trainlineID and station ID And i am doing autocomplete by binding data through class

Comment: @VMaleev yes i do use MVVM patern

Comment: I am not sure if my comment will be of any value to your situation, however, why not use twitter typeahead(for example) on your client side. Use an ajax call to a server method that gets a javaserialised string of a preloaded list of train lines and stations. Then specify in the typeahead the textboxes and the respective data that will be filled when a select event of the typeahead is fired

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a public property which will contains selected train Line/Airline and use the value of that property in your query defined in StationDataProvider class.